# Angular Firebase Reachig Child array of an Item

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had an issue with reaching items under key. My firebase structure is like down below:

[image: Firebase data]

In code part I can reach the key value but I cant list the values under key such as '2' key.

My html part is like the code below:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of listRequest;let i=index">
        <tr>{{item.key}}</tr>
      <td><button >Approve</button> </td>
</li>
```

This is how I pull datas from firebase(service part):

```
return  this.db.list('/requestCourses/').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => changes
           .map(c => ({key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()}))));
```

Comment: what does c.payload.val() give you?

Comment: Gives me the data in the picture I posted. But I wanna reach the uid fields value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `uid`, you can do the following:

First in the service class do the following:

```
getItems()
{
return this.db.list('/requestCourses/').snapshotChanges();
}

getSubItems(key)
{
return this.db.list('/requestCourses/' + key + "/").snapshotChanges();
}
```

Then in the component you can subsribe:

```
this.getItems().subscribe(items => {
    items.forEach(values =>{
    let key = values.key;
    getSubItems(key).subscribe(subItems => {
       subItems.forEach(uid => {
         console.log(uid.payload.val());
         });
       });
     });
   });
```

Here first add a reference to node `requestCourses`, then add `snapshotChanges()` which returns an `Observable`, and using `subscribe` you can retrieve the array that contains the `key`.

Then using the `key` you can add a reference to the node `key`, subscribe to the `Observable` and iterate in the array to get the `uid`.

Comment: I could not run .forEach part

Comment: why couldnt u run foreach part what is the console.log returning?!

Comment: Gives this error: ERROR TypeError: values.forEach is not a function

Comment: what does this `console.log(items);` give you

Comment: [{…}]
0:
payload: DataSnapshot {node_: ChildrenNode, ref_: Reference, index_: PriorityIndex}
type: "value"
prevKey: null
key: "uB4YWoYUsJSVwAoBB0gE2aYwgi62"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: what about `console.log(items.payload.key)`